# exit function not working because of the except

Tags: python, exit

When I try to use the `exit()` function, the code does not stop because of the exception, how do I cancel it?

```
def start(number):
    try:
        print(9 ** number)
        exit()
    except:
        print("problem")
        start()
```

Comment: That's one of the reasons you shouldn't use bare `except:`. Be more specific about what could go wrong, *at most* `except Exception:`; see https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to look at the [Exception Hierarchy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy) in the manual. The base exception is appropriately named `BaseException`, and every other exception inherits from it. There are four direct descendants of `BaseException`: `SystemExit`, `KeyboardInterrupt`, `GeneratorExit` and `Exception`.

`exit` raises a `SystemExit` exception, which you're catching with your unconditional `except` clause. Usually you only want to catch `Exception` and any of its descendants, which are all other exceptions. So:

```
try:
    ...
except Exception:
    ...
```

This allows the three other kinds of exceptions to bubble up as they should and allows you to catch the more specific tree of exceptions. Preferably you'd catch only even more specific types, as specific as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You are catching every exception, including `SystemExit`.

Use `except Exception` in order to catch all built-in, non exiting exceptions.

In your specific case, I would suggest only catching a `TypeError`, because that's what you would expect to be thrown for bad types of `number`. That is, after you fix the argument-less call to `start()` in the except-block, which will raise a `TypeError` itself.